# When is c++ Preferable to JavaScript in Qt 5.7 for Performance?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, benchmarking

**tl;dr version**:

Is there a benchmark or syntax examples of when (if ever) to use `c++` instead of `JS` in `Qt 5.7` and/or to define the performance of `JS` vs. `c++` in `Qt 5.7` confirming the latter is indeed faster as the *Documentation* for the project states.

---

**In-Depth Background**

I'm somewhat new to the world of `QML`/`Qt` and am trying to learn best practices and ways to in general deliver a fast and robust code suitable for eventual deployment on embedded systems.

As a long time c++ developer who's occasionally dabbled in `JavaScript`, I've always heard from more experienced `JS` developers that in most cases `c++` code compiled on a fast compiler like `icpc` with optimizations will outperform `JS` even in compiled bytecode form ([in-depth Mozilla Dev blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20160729200156/https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/08/01/staring-at-the-sun-dalvik-vs-spidermonkey/) discussing this).  That's indeed been my own limited experience with `JS`.

Hence, I was somewhat surprised to read that for `Qt 5.7` the "[Qt Documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20160729194016/http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/index.html)" > "[Performance Considerations And Suggestions](http://web.archive.org/web/20160729194055/http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html)" > "`Javascript`" states:

> Most QML applications will have a large amount of JavaScript code in
>   them, in the form of dynamic functions, signal handlers, and property
>   binding expressions. This is generally not a problem. Thanks to some
>   optimizations in the QML engine, such as those done to the bindings
>   compiler, it can (in some use-cases) be faster than calling a C++
>   function. However, care must be taken to ensure that unnecessary
>   processing isn't triggered accidentally.

This comment paints a pretty interesting picture, but I was unable to locate much information in terms of real world test cases regarding this.

---

**The Questions: Quantifying Qt Application c++ vs. JS in the Real World**

My questions are:

1. What constitutes "***unnecessary processing***" in `Javascript`?
2. How is said "***unnecessary processing***" triggered?
3. Is there any case when `c++` will still confer a performance advantage over `JS` for use with `QML`/`Qt` code? (IO?)

---

**Examples of Quantifiable Performance Info Pertaining to Qt Javascript**

To give a couple examples of the kind of quantifiable information I've been searching for in order to define the statement in *Documentation* I found these `qml` specific examples.  While neither relates to my question, they seem to be good examples of the kind of information needed to make meaningful sense of the *Documentation*'s statement:

- [Qt Developer Adventures - Simple QML vs EFL comparison](http://web.archive.org/web/20160729194707/http://tolszak-dev.blogspot.com/2013/02/simple-qml-vs-efl-comparison.html)
- [Qt Blog: New Scene Graph Renderer](http://web.archive.org/web/20160729194822/https://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/09/02/new-scene-graph-renderer/)

Both of which have some nice graphs illustrating a quantifiable benchmark of `QML` implemented `Qt` (w/ `Javascript` calls) versus some other code/version.  The issue is I've been able to locate nothing like this for `c++` vs. `JS` performance.  Hence it's hard to try to understand exactly how much better `JS` performance is vs. `c++` for `Qt` code, if indeed it's better as the *Documentation* claims.  Also it's difficult to identify how to avoid the pitfall discussed without this kind of information.

Comment: It's not about performance. You do the pure UI parts in js: the ones that are very far from the application data that is actually processed. Everything else should be in C++. So, if you have js functions with loops and stuff to work with data, it will become unmaintainable very fast. About performance: there are UI items that need to receive so much volatile data (like some point cloud renderers), so they can't be supplied by the ListModels/ItemModels: these items should be implemented in C++ for the performance reasons.

Comment: @Velkan So you know for sure that looped calculations give a performance disadvantage if implemented with `JavaScript` in current version of  Qt, rather than `c++`?  Just checking because the Documentation states `unnecessary processing`, which seems to imply some sort of redundant/unwanted operation.  It does not state any qualifications regarding `necessary processing`, and further says `JavaScript` will generally be faster.  Looped operations are processing intensive, but may be very "necessary."  Thoughts?

Comment: In case of looped calculations I wasn't talking about performance. I just said that it's hard to maintain that kind of code. (and then saw also the same thoughts in "Qt DevDays 2011, Qt Quick Best Practices and Design Patterns: Girish Ramakrishnan" video on 3:50)

Comment: There is redundant processing in JS trough variables and properties lookup by string name and performing integer computations in floating point. As a rule of thumb, you lose about two orders of magnitude in performance when using JS through the QML V4 engine compared to C++.